# How to Create Formula with Excel Averageifs Using 2 criteria, including a range

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I'm having a hard time getting this excel averageif formula to work.

I'm trying to combine 2 criteria using an external reference.

The first criteria is that the a range in an external worksheet matches a line in the current worksheet (i.e. that's the external reference)

If there is a match, the averageif calculates only if the figure from the range is less than 300.

I have this so far (that's not working):

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Mission!$A$1:$A$122,"="&C4,Mission!$C$1:$C$122,"<300")
```

I also tried: =AVERAGE(IF((Mission!$A$1:$A$122,"="&C4)+(Mission!$C$1:$C$122"<300"),Mission!$C$1:$C$122))

Comment: Please don't use comments to add information to your original post. Edit the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Mission!$C$1:$C$122,Mission!$A$1:$A$122,C4,Mission!$C$1:$C$122,"<"&300)
```

Screenshots of my data:

[image: Sheet1]

[image]